# Rails - Create multiple resources from javascript/coffeescript datas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources

Suppose I've a model : **Thing**

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :url
```

In my coffeescript, I've a function generating an array of JSON objects, eg:

```
[{"url":"https://www.example.com/1","name":"1"},
{"url":"https://www.example.com/2","name":"2"},
{"url":"https://www.example.com/3","name":"3"}]
```

That function is called when the user click on a button in the *index* page of **Thing**.

What I want is create multiple **Thing** resources based on the JSON objects generated by the coffeescript function.

What is the best way to do it?
I'm considering using Ajax to redirect to the create action of **Thing** but not sure this is the best way.

Thanks

Comment: a little unclear if you want all those created - will probably want to ride some custom validation in case of things like dupes or validation.

Comment: Yes I want all those created. No need to bother about dupes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, AJAX is the way to go. What you'd do is submit these objects to the controller where you'd make your `Thing` models.

If you're submitting all of those objects and once and want them all created in one shot you could do that in the `create` action or you could do that in a `create_all` action. I like the idea of a `create_all` action because it's letting us know it's not a simple `create` action where people have learned to assume it just makes 1 of an object. This is a personal preference though.

Comment: Thanks Adam, do you have any good AJAX example to achieve this?

Comment: Railscasts puts it in a rails context. Enjoy http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised and http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax

Comment: This is nice screencasts but I already know them, the difference with what I want to do is that I didn't work with forms (html) but my datas are generated via javascript.

Comment: I will add that reference to your answer and I think we're good : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474505/ajax-for-creating-multiple-records-in-rails Tell me if you think I'm not going to the right direction with this link.